# pulling one field of a record into an array in a Rails 3 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Rails 3 noob here. Currently the code in my controller below is getting the whole record in my database. I am trying to populate the array with one integer, not the whole record. The integer is contained in a table "answers" and the field name is "score". How can i modify this line in my controller to get just the one field?

```
@questions.each do |s|
   @ans[s.position] = Answer.where("question_id = ? AND user_id = ?", s.q_id, current_user.id )
end
```

UPDATE FOR CLARIFICATION: The :score can be any integer from 0 to 5. I would like to populate @ans[s.position] with the integer.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're very close

```
@questions.each do |s|
  @ans[s.position] = Answer.where("question_id = ? and user_id = ?",s.q_id,current_user.id).select(:score).first.try(:score)
end
```

You need to select "score" from Answer, then you need to retrieve it from the object.

Comment: excellent. thanks. i am wondering why the ".select(:score)" portion. everything works without it. am i missing something?

Comment: This ensures that the underlying select query does not do a "select * from table.." but only "select score from table ..". Why select all the fields when you know you only need one (score).

Answer (score 1):

Since `where` could potentially return many `Answer`s, use `first` to pull off the first `Answer`, and then `score` to project out the score field.

```
answers = Answer.where("question_id = ? AND user_id = ?", s.q_id, current_user.id )
score = answers.first.score
```

All together it would be:

```
@questions.each do |s|
   @ans[s.position] = Answer.where("question_id = ? AND user_id = ?", s.q_id, current_user.id ).first.score
end
```

As an optimization to only retrieve `score` from the database, instead of `answers.*`, you could use `select(:score)`.

```
@questions.each do |s|
   @ans[s.position] = Answer.where("question_id = ? AND user_id = ?", s.q_id, current_user.id ).select(:score).first.score
end
```

See [Active Record Query Interface](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#selecting-specific-fields) for more about using `select`.

Comment: there will only be one answer per user per question. If there is more than one, then somehow the system would be broken. I'm wondering if I ought to leave ".first" out. If there were an error then it would reveal there was a problem somewhere.

Comment: ah... never mind on the comment. i removed it and the app threw an error. So I am seeing the relevance now. Thanks.

Comment: Updated answer w/ explanation of `select` and link to Ruby on Rails Guides for more help.

Answer (score 0):

Just `include` them.

```
@questions = Question.includes(:answers).select(:position)
```

Or use this

```
@questions = Question.select(:position)
@questions.each{ |s| @ans[s.position] = s.answers.where(:user_id => current_user.id) }
```

Comment: i tried your solutions and variations of them. In each case the app threw errors. Your solutions are beyond my abilities to understand enough to make adjustments that would work. Thank you though.